# How to translate odoo custom modules related fields? (ir.module.module model fields: name, description, summary, ...)

Tags: module, odoo, translation, radix

I'm a odoo community v10-11-12-13 module developper and I can't figure out how to translate the module informations from manifest file that are written in English.
I can see that some core modules names and summary are translated in the Application list when a language is added, but these translations are written in base/i18n/ folder...

- Have I to modify base module files to add translations of my custom modules? Or is there another way?
- How to ship these translations with my module code base? (aka how can my modules write lines in base/i18n/xx.po files?)

EDIT: I'm not asking how to translate the content of my custom module's strings (model, views, ...) but the **module's informations** that stands in the module's manifest and static/description/index.html files. So the fields **shortdesc, summary, description_html of the ir.module.module** model.
I had looked the documentation about translating and it speaks about exporting the module's strings only, where the ir.module.module fields are not.
I'm able to export base module .pot file (where the ir.module.module fields are) but then I don't know where to put this translations because the i18n folder can't have several module.pot nor several xx.po files for different modules in it.
So I don't how to merge it to my module's .pot file...

Thanks

Comment: I'm just wondering: did you read [Translating Modules](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/translations.html)?

Comment: I tried also to merge base translations in "my_module.pot" (so some with comments #. module: my_module and some with #. module: base ) and it didn't seems to work

Comment: Do i understand it correct, that you try to translate fields from other modules than your own?

Comment: I was just asking if you're able to delete comments... You answered it's not you... OK ! It's weird! I did give some extra info in it so I'm a bit confused why it has been deleted...
I understand people ask questions without reading the doc... On my part I a bit disappointed of reading RTFM so often !!

Comment: Concerning the question: it's quite clear, I'm asking how to translate module name (shortdesc) and summary that shows in Application list ... Nothing else, not the module's content strings, not another module's string, just optionally the base module where the ir.module.module instances are registered (if this is the way to translate module's informations)...

Comment: Well now that is a very good question i can't answer, but atleast upvote ;-)